# rsync transfer 'Broken pipe (32)' connection dropping

Tags: bash, debian, ssh, rsync, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a small script to transfer a lot of images from a proxmox VM to a raspberry pi on the same LAN (around 90 GB of images/videos).
This is not always working as intended, since I keep experiencing the rsync connection dropping at random. This is not happening on the same file or directory. This changes every time it fails.
The error I am getting is:

```
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)  
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] sent 8888398299 bytes  received 24769 bytes  total size 43016448521  
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(823) [sender=3.2.3]
```

I feel like I have been all around the internet by now. Or else it is just because I am not searching for the right keywords.
I've tried to add `ServerAliverInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to `~/.ssh/config` on the sending host to no avail.
Others suggest that it might have to do with a lack of memory. I am not entirely sure how one would test this, but I have kept an eye on the memory usage on the sending host, as well as the receiving end, this doesn't seem to be the problem either. Again, I do not know how to be sure about this.

Some then suggest that you use scp instead of rsync. I just don't like the idea of changing, since I would like to use some of the features of rsync down the line (such as file matching).
Also, I don't see the reason to change, since this gotta work somehow.

Here's a little about my setup:

- Sender: Proxmox VM (docker host)

  - 4 CPU cores (Proxmox host running on i5-8259U)
  - 6 GB RAM (usually 500 MB free RAM + 4 GB swap)
- Receiver: Raspberry Pi 4B

  - 4 GB RAM

VM is running a fully updated Debian, and the Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian OS - also fully updated. It should also be noted that the rsync version is the same on both hosts.

While rsync was running, I have tried to have a continuous ping going. This does not show any sign of network problems.
I have also tried to have another ssh session from the sending machine to the receiver. This connection does not drop when the file transfer fails.
Does anyone have a clue to what I can try to make this work?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Check if script has root privileges #
if [[ "$EUID" -ne '0' ]]
  then echo "Missing root privileges"
  exit
fi

if [[ "$EUID" -eq '0' ]]; then
  echo "Root privileges - check"
    if ! rsync -caPv --log-file="/home/user/backup-outputs/datalibrary-transfer-$(date +"%d%m%Y").log" '/srv/docker/datalibrary/' backup@192.168.1.200:"/home/backup/backup-stuff/datalibrary-$(date +"%d%m%Y")/" ; then
    mv "/home/user/backup-outputs/datalibrary-transfer-$(date +"%d%m%Y").log" "/home/user/backup-outputs/datalibrary-transfer-$(date +"%d%m%Y")-failed.log" 
    fi
  else
    echo "Unknown error" > /home/user/backup-outputs/error.log
fi
```

This is the rsync version of the two hosts:
VM:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31

Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    SIMD, asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
```

RPi:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31

Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 32-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    no SIMD, no asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
```

Comment: I mean this sounds like the unreliable part is there RPi; did you check it's logs?

Comment: I'd seriously recommend removing the `-c` (`--checksum`) option from your `rsync` invocation

Comment: What are the filesystems involved here? Linux-native or NTFS?

Comment: Also, since you're running on the client as root but a non-privileged account on the destination, I would also include `-M--fake-super -X` to store metadata attributes correctly. Probably won't resolve the connection breakage but it will mean you're creating a "more correct" backup

Comment: Checked the CPU usage at the RPi? The `-c` checksum check might cost to much CPU or I/O. Test to limit the bandwidth `--bwlimit=RATE` to get in balance with the RPi's I/O

Comment: @MarcusMûller if you mean dmesg and journalctl logs, then there is nothing to be found in them.

Comment: @roaima I know that `-c` will use more CPU on the RPi, but while the transfer is in progress, it is never loaded to the absolute max. Is there any other reason I sould remove it?

Comment: @roaima The filesystem I am using on the proxmox host is ZFS, while the RPi is running ext4. I will also add the extra attributes to store the files correctly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @dodrg I have tried to run a job, while keeping an eye out for the CPU usage. It isn't what I would classify as max loaded at any time of the transfer. A random thread sometimes jumps to 100% load, while the others sit at around 70-80%. This isn't for long however. What would you suggest I try setting the `--bwlimit` parameter to? 10 megabytes?

Comment: @786yt hm, sad. The one common cause of trouble on the Rpi is that the SD cards from which the system runs becomes unreliable (SD cards are rarely actually meant for random read/write access that running an operating system on it brings). But you'd see that in dmesg. Same for the so-and-so quality of the network interface on the RPi4. TCP would have your back, unless the connection totally breaks down, and you'd see that in journalctl (not necessarily in a Ping, which can just happen to be in between breakdowns). Hm. Did you try running rsync with `--remote-option=--log-file=/tmp/rsync.log`?

Comment: (that'd give you remote-side logs)

Comment: @786yt The value for `--bwlimit` is a thing of testing. My first hint would be the half of the average transfer speed you've seen without limit, then reducing/increasing by the half depending on the result then etc. . But starting with `--bwlimit=10m` is also ok.

Comment: The `-c` flag tests remote files with a checksum every time you attempt a copy. Using `-t` _instead_ will bypass checksumming when the file size and time is identical on both sides, and automatically fall back to using a checksum when the time differs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller First off. So terribly sorry about my late reply. Life has really been busy as heck lately!
I have tried the `remote-option` you suggested. That doesn't really help me much. Returns this:
`rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (523550 bytes received so far) [generator]`

Comment: @MarcusMüller continuation: `rsync error: errors with program diagnostics (code 13) at log.c(245) [generator=3.2.3]` and finally `rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)`

Comment: but that's from the /tmp/rsync.log of the *remote* machine, right?

Comment: Correct. From the remote machine. Also I see that I forgot to answer you @MarcusMüller regarding the underlying storage hardware. The backups are stored on an external SSD, hooked up via USB 3.0. Just to get it out of the question, I am using wired ethernet, but this is however still hooked up to the standard network interface.